# how to have 2 elements next to each other in a nav bar?

Tags: html, css

I have done a lot of looking around and cant quite mine to work, i was hoping with my specific code people would be able to help.
here is the html:

```
<body>
<!-- <h3> Website Title </h3> -->
<ul id="navigationBarList">
  <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Bookings">Bookings</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Blog">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Pricing">Pricing</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="element2"> Sign in </div>



</body>
```

and here is the css:

```
#navigationBarList{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: black;    
    font-size: 25px;
    color: red;
    width: 100%;
}
#navigationBarList li{
    display: inline;
    width: 100px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
#element2{
    display: inline;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

and simply i want the sign in link to be on the same line as the list items. (the reason i have not included it in the list is that i want the list to have equal space in between each element and then a wider gap with the sign in button shoved to the right of the screen but could not work it out so figured i should separate them)

so far this code is just shoving it underneath

Comment: You should look into how to use the css float property. float-left and float-right

Comment: is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/efr8tkm2/) what you want???

Comment: possible duplicate of [vertical alignment of elements in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div)

Comment: Your problem is that you set your `<ul>` element as 100% width. How do you plan on fitting in the `Sign in` link?

Comment: @Lal sort of but i want the sign in to be same height as the black nav bar

Comment: @Phylogenesis I want it go over the top of it or inside it if you see what i mean. so it's sort of encapsulated.

Comment: You can `position` the `#element2` element `absolute` like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/rjaa32bb/). Is that the look you're after?

Comment: @Phylogenesis yeh that's good. would you be able to explain to me how i can get it to look like your example but have 'sign in' as part of the original list? i.e. chose the individual space between each item in a horizontal list?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add to add `float: right` to  `#element2` and remove `width: 100%;` from `#navigationBarList`, then add `font-size: 25px;` to `#element2`.

```css
#navigationBarList{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: black;    
    font-size: 25px;
    color: red;
}
#navigationBarList li{
    display: inline;
    width: 100px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}
#element2{
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    font-size: 25px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<body>
<!-- <h3> Website Title </h3> -->
<ul id="navigationBarList">
  <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Bookings">Bookings</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Blog">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Pricing">Pricing</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="element2"> Sign in </div>



</body>
```

A **cleaner approach** could look like this

```css
#navigationBarList{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
    /*
    display: inline-block; 
    margin: 0;
    margin-right: 10px; add this to the list
    padding: 10px; add this to anchors
    background-color: black; add this to the list    
    font-size: 25px; you can add this to #element2,#navigationBarList
    color: red;  add this to anchors
    width: 100%; you don't need this
    */
}
#navigationBarList li{
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    background-color: black
}
#navigationBarList a{
    margin-right: 10px;
    color: red;
    padding: 20px;
}
#element2{
    float: right;
    background-color: red;
}
#element2,#navigationBarList{
    font-size: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!-- <h3> Website Title </h3> -->
<ul id="navigationBarList">
  <li><a href="#About">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Bookings">Bookings</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Blog">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="#Pricing">Pricing</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="element2"> Sign in </div>
```

Comment: Could you provide an explanation with your answer? _Try this_ kind of solutions are not welcome here.